# Domain of Laplacian

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis

Let $L$ be an operator on $C^2(\mathbb R)$, defined by
$$L \phi (x) = \int_{|y|<1} (\phi(x+y) - \phi(x) - \phi'(x) \ y)\ \nu(dy), \text{ for all } x\in \mathbb R$$
for a measure $\nu(dy) = |y|^{-2} dy$. It is evident that $L\phi$ is well-defined for $\phi\in C^2$ since$$|\phi(x+y) - \phi(x) - \phi'(x) \ y| \le K_x y^2$$in $B_1(x)$. Note that the definition of $L$ is explicitly dependent up to the first derivative of $\phi$.

**Question.** Is there a function $\phi \in C^1 \setminus C^2$, such that $L \phi $ is not well-defined?

Comment: It's not clear what the precise technical meaning is that you want to attach to "well defined;" can you please clarify.

Comment: In particular, following @ChristianRemling's question, do you want $L\varphi$ to not merely be "(well?-) defined" in some ill-defined sense, but a continuous map from $C^2(\mathbb R)$ to another topological vector space, and you're asking whether it extends to be a continuous map from $C^1(\mathbb R)$ to a perhaps-larger TVS? Or, perhaps, is the refinement to this meta-question the question you wanted to ask?

Comment: Is it $L$ you call _Laplacian_?? Seems unusual...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$L\phi$ is a convolution with a distribution with compact support, thus it is "well defined" at least as a distribution, for any $\phi\in\cal D'$. A closer look reveals $L$ maps $H^s$ to $H^{s-1}$, $\forall s\in\mathbb R$. Indeed, this operator is a truncated version of the (positive) **square root** of (minus) the Laplacian, that multiplies $\hat\phi(\xi)$ with a constant times $|\xi|$. (It **doesn't** map $C^1$ to $C^0$, however).